# 2 column layout with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 column layout with both 100% height.
The problem is when the right column with content is larger then the left content where the menu will be the left column is empty when i scroll down.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
            <br /><p>test test test</p>
        </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
             height:100%;
    }

    body {
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #container {
        height:100%;
    }

    #left {
        float:left;
        width:200px;
        background-color:blue;
        min-height: 100% !important;
    }

    #right {
        margin:0 0 0 0px;
        background-color:red;
        width:1000px;
        min-height: 100% !important;
        float:left;
    }

    .clearfix {         
        clear: both;
    }
```

And here is a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/F9rdh/) to demonstrate...

Comment: That's the whole point of `height:100%` - to take up 100% of available screen space - thus if the content doesn't cause it to extend, it won't naturally do so.

Comment: do you want the right column to scroll within when the content is longer? Or do you want the left column to adhere to the right column's height?

Comment: looks like the right column's height is extending past the container's height

Comment: I would like the left column to be the exact height as the right column, is there any possible way ?

Comment: Have a look at http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ - there are a lot of different approaches to full height columns. I particularly like the faux-background technique as a quick and easy approach

Comment: a thoughtless solution could be to use javascript if you're interested in that

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that you must set the height of 100% to the body and html tag, then set the height to 100% on each div element you want to make 100% the height of the page, futher check below links:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aeinbu/QDBff/35/) and 
    [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raver0124/QDBff/36/)

Basic one would be:

```
 .table{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 12px;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 49%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 12px;
}
.cell2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 49%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin 12px;
}
.inner {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

Hope, it helps !